# Change jQuery depending on where user is on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a navigation where the background comes in after the user scrolls down. However, when the user is in the middle of the page, and refreshes, the background disappears and they need to scroll again for it to reappear. I'm trying to make it so whenever the user has scrolled past the header, the navigation background colour will be there no matter what.

Any help would be appreciated!

Code:

Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  var targetOffset = $('header').offset().top + $('header').height();

  var $w = $(window).scroll(function(){
      if ( $w.scrollTop() > targetOffset ) {
          $("#nav").css('background-color', 'rgba(35,46,63,1)');
      } else {
        $('#nav').css('background-color', 'rgba(35,46,63,0)');
      }
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    background-color: rgba(35,46,63,0);
    transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

nav > .wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav > .wrapper > li.nav-logo {
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

nav > .wrapper > li.nav-logo > a {
    color: #DDDDDD;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav > .wrapper > li.nav-logo > a > img.left {
    width: 5%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

nav > .wrapper > ul.right {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}

nav > .wrapper > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-radius: 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

nav > .wrapper > ul > li > a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

nav > .wrapper > ul > li > a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <li class="nav-logo"><a href="#"><img class="left" src="assets/images/ugn-logos/single-ugn-logo.png" alt="ugn-logo"></a></li>
        <span class="nav-btn"><i class="icon-menu"></i></span>
        <ul class="right">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="shared-hosting.html">Shared Hosting</a></li>
            <li><a href="vps.html">VPS</a></li>
            <li><a href="minecraft.html">Minecraft</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: have you tried using waypoints.js?

Comment: Plenty of examples out there on fixed header on scrolling, have you looked at those?

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at a few. I can't find any that help with the issue of users refreshing and having to scroll for it to reappear.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `$(window).scroll()` will only activate once a scroll has occurred. The same script needs to happen on `$(document).ready()`. So you can create a function and call it on window resize and document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function changeBG() {
    var targetOffset = $('header').offset().top + $('header').height();

    if ( $w.scrollTop() > targetOffset ) {
      $("#nav").css('background-color', 'rgba(35,46,63,1)');
    } else {
      $('#nav').css('background-color', 'rgba(35,46,63,0)');
    }
  }

  changeBG();

  $(window).scroll(changeBG);

});
```

Comment: You don't need to create an extra anonymous function. Just: $(window).scroll(changeBG)

Comment: I'm a bit of a jQuery noob, would I need to replace my entire code with this? Or do I need to put it in somewhere specific?

Comment: The jQuery code I have provided would replace the jQuery code you have provided. It is exactly the same as your script, but now it is been called when the page is ready and when it is scrolled. The only reason I have put it in to a function is so you don't have to repeat the same code twice.

Comment: @WizardCoder: you might want to edit again: `$(window).scroll(changeBG);` to properly pass reference to `changeBG` function.

Comment: @HuguesMoreau Thanks. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$( document ).load(function(){ /* your code */ });
```